# Do all non-PVP battles give the same amount of EXP?

Tags: gems-of-war

Do all non-PVP battles give the same amount of EXP?

I did some class quest battles, and some explore LV1 battles, but even though the former is harder than the latter, they gave the same amount of EXP.

Is this true for all battles other than PVP ones, which I heard give more EXP?

Answer (score 1):

You'll generally get more XP by pushing your Kingdoms Power Levels and regular levels, as well as your Hero and Class levels.

Quickly try to get all Kingdoms to Level 10, and Power Level 6 or better. Follow by maxing out your favorite Class, or at least getting the Class Weapon for 250 wins.

Then you want to push ALL of your Hero levels to at least 10, the. 20, then 40, and higher.